# Android phone number linkify

Tags: android, linkify

I have a phone number that is being linkified on Android 4+ devices.

```
Linkify.addText(textView,pattern,scheme);
```

The problem I have is that extensions are not recognized by the phone. I have tried adding commas and p/w to no avail. I have also tried a webview with an anchor element instead of a linkified textview to the same result. Everytime only the phone number is dialed and never the extension. Has anyone been able to get extensions working on Android 4+ and if so what was your method?

For the textView string I would have the following:

"8001234567,555"

The number is dialed correctly but the extension is not added.

Comment: It might be helpful if you added samples of working and not working numbers.